# Cross Product Calculation Question Given Orthogonality Conditions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, cross-product

Suppose that vectors $u$, $v$, $w$ are mutually orthogonal. Compute $(u \times v) \times w$ and $u \times (v \times w)$

Wouldn't we simply multiply $u$ and $v$ and $w$ all together? Or is there a formula I'm missing here?

Comment: What does this "product" of vectors mean? Is it the dot product/cross product? Please provide a definition of this operation

Comment: If it's a dot product you get $0$, if it's a cross product you also get $0$.

Comment: For mutually orthogonal vectors, $u \cdot v = v \cdot w = 0.$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I can't give any more info because there was no more provided than what I already said. My professor has a real way with words

Comment: @ астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг  It must be a vector product, because a dot product doesn't make sense, unless you have a dot product and the product of a scalar by a vector both written as *.

Comment: @BernardMassé What you say is true, but one cannot write an answer without confirming that this is indeed the case.

Comment: Your professor actually used $*$ and not $\cdot$ or $\times$ ?

Comment: @bof Oh my bad, they used ×. I didn't know how to write that out

Comment: Oh well. The \times operator, or $\times$ , is standard notation for the cross product. Now this question is more answerable.

Comment: [MathJax Basic Tutorial And Quick Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in order for this to make sense. Now, $(u\times v)\perp u$ and $(u\times v)\perp v$, so that $u\times v$ must be a scalar multiple of $w$, i.e. $u\times v=\lambda w$. So, $(u\times v)\times w=\lambda w\times w=0.$

The computation of $u\times(v\times w)$ is analogous.